# How to delete '\' from a text?

Tags: python, regex

How can i delete '\' from a text ?
Like this :

```
import re
my_source = re.sub('\', '', my_source)
```

Is it correct ?

Comment: *"Is it correct?"* Does it work? If not then it's probably not correct.

Comment: Really, you just asked almost the same exact question twice in the same hour.

Comment: No. i didn't know i should use 's.replace("\\", "")' instead 's.replace("\", "")' . ok ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you asked two very similar questions in quick succession of each other, I will simply modify my answer from the first question to answer this question.

```
>>> my_source = r'AB\CDEFG_HI(JKLM).NOP'
>>> deletions = ('_', r'\', '(', ')', 'EF', 'O')
>>> for deletion in deletions:
...     my_source = my_source.replace(deletion, "")
... 
>>> my_source
'ABCDGHIJKLM.NP'
```

Answer (score 5):

Why use regex for such a simple task. Use [`str.replace()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.replace):

```
>>> s = "Hello \\ world \ !"
>>> s.replace("\\", "")
'Hello  world  !'
```